# Webpack Stenciljs PWA

Tags: ionic-framework, webpack, stenciljs

I need to reduce the size of a Stenciljs PWA for a project using Webpack. The Stenciljs Compiler creates several JS files and embeds them as nomodule script tag in the index.html file.

Now my questions:

- Is there a way to combine all scripts (e.g. with gulp)?
- Is there a way to get Stenciljs not to include the JS files using nomodule script tag? This is not resolved by webpack.

Answer (score 2):

Stencil already does its best to generate optimized bundles that are minified in production builds. I doubt you'll be able to minify this much further with Webpack. Don't be fooled by checking the size of the output folder (`www` if it's an app), as it doesn't represent the size of what's actually loaded when you open the app in the browser.

There's no way to combine all scripts into one by simply concatenating the scripts, as that's against the nature of ES modules (one file per module). You could try the `dist-custom-elements-bundle` output target (https://stenciljs.com/docs/custom-elements), which allows you to create only one bundle that includes all your components. However that is a dist-type output target, so you'll have to figure out how to consume that for your app.

Stencil doesn't embed any `nomodule` script tags in your index.html. Maybe you meant `rel="modulepreload"`?

> In addition, all the metadata collected by the compiler and the dependency graph generated by rollup can be used to automatically create “modulepreload” links, reducing the amount of network round-trips required to download all the JS in the critical path to zero. This drastically reduces the Time-To-Interactive of apps built with Stencil.

(from https://ionicframework.com/blog/announcing-stencil-one-beta/)

The only `nomodule`-type script that would be in your `src/index.html` is the one with the entry point for your app for browsers that don't support `type="module"`. It's added by default, see [src/index.html#L22](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-pwa-toolkit/blob/8c9efdd2a8e106e2d62839217ef0cb98e0c040a7/src/index.html#L22). This script will be ignored (i. e. not loaded) by browsers that already support ES modules. However it's up to you to remove it, your app just won't work in any browsers that don't support ES modules then.

If you want to drop support for IE11 and old Edge (before v18), you can use the `extras` option in your `stencil.config.ts`, which might reduce the size further:

```js
export const config: Config = {
  buildEs5: false,
  extras: {
    dynamicImportShim: false,
    cssVarsShim: false,
    shadowDomShim: false,
    scriptDataOpts: false,
    safari10: false
  }
}
```

(see https://stenciljs.com/docs/config-extras)

Comment: hello I am try use stencil in webapck5 and buidl a mirco-front-end app with webpack5 ModuleFederation I hope stencil project work as container and load vue and react project, but I can not find any article about this. Can i build stencil with webpack? how?

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with this answer but yeah I guess you can build a Stencil project with an output target that's consumable by webpack. Answering how to do that won't fit into a comment though and doesn't belong there anyway.